# How can i transfer an already published app to a different company yet remain developer of it

Tags: ios, app-store

My Company A has built an app and published it on the store under our account.
After some time Company B contracted us to develop a branded version of our app for them.
We did that and published it on our store account.
Now Company B would like the app to be published under their app account. Because it is only a branded version we do not want to "transfer ownership" of the app, only publishing rights, as we want to remain the developer and will have to maintain the app etc.

The Apple guideline sounds like you have to completely transfer everything to Company B.
I am VERY confused about all that.

How would it work ? Company B gives me a publishing certificate and XCode knows where to upload it to ? I click "submit app" in XCode and Company B receives it in iTunes connect but has no real access to the app other than the uploaded package ?! How would they install it for screenshots etc ?!

But to stick to SO rules, the QUESTION here is: How do i only transfer the publishing stuff to Company B but keep the code and everything else in house.

Comment: NikkyD please use following link for Apple guide lines it will help you for transfer the app. 

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

Comment: Please edit your link, the last ']' is included within it ;)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

Comment: Please go thru above link.

Comment: Those guidelines talk about COMPLETE transfer, not just publishing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to transfer the app ownership to company B, you can follow [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html) by Apple. (thanks to @Madhav comments)

But what happen if you must continue working on this app ?

First, you have to use a production certificate from company B (you can still use your debug ones). Since the number of production certificate for a account is limited, company B has two choices :

- If you are the only one external developer to work with company B, you can reserve one of these production certificate. Generate the `.certSigningRequest` file as if you wanted to create a certificate, send it to company B and ask them to generate the **App Store and Ad Hoc** certificate. With the `.cer` file they will send you and the private key you have generated, you can now work with this production certificate.
- If the company B is working with multiple external developers, they should have kept one of their production certificate slot for external developers. They have to provide you both the `.cer` file and the private key.

They must also provide you a provisioning profile for the App you're working on.

You're now able to build App with their account. If they want to generate screenshots for the app by themselves, you can use [TestFlight beta testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH35).

Comment: Just to clarify, B would own the app entirely and i am "just" holding the source code. I can't do anything without their certs and they can't do anything without me and the source ?!

Comment: You own the code and `B` is unable to alter it in any way or create a new version of the app without referring to you. But the app is owned by `B`, which can decide to remove it from the App Store, or can revoke the distribution certificate you use (in this case, they would have to start back from scratch, except in you are red to give them the source code, but I'm not an expert on legal issues to be honest)

Answer (score 0):

@NikkyD

Please use following link for Apple guide lines it will help you for transfer the app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html